# Vue/Webpack: split CSS into 2 files based on condition

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

I have a Vue project with SCSS included in .vue files.
I need the styles for *some* of the components to get compiled into a CSS file called global.css, and the rest into another file (let's call it default.css).

I want to be able to decide easily which component styles go where and was thinking of using something like this, if it's even possible:

```
<style lang="scss" global>
/* SCSS goes here */
</style>
```

So basically I'm trying to find a way to split the styles using the *global* keyword.
If a component has the global keyword, its styles should go into global.css, otherwise into default.css.

Is this even possible? Am I embarking on something super complex?
Any other idea as to how I could achieve this in another way if so?

Comment: I also use single-file components as you but I don't include the styles in the components. You can create a global stylesheet included in main.js and put your global styles there (here is the excellent explanation for it by Thorsten Lünborg - he is a very skilled Vue ninja: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/328#issuecomment-249206638) and include in the components only the local styles.

Comment: You have also other options like namespacing your style tags, more info here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#using-with-pre-processors

Comment: @user9685408 Why would you spread global styles across components instead of a single global stylesheet (as Máté Wiszt suggested)?

Comment: It's because our site works with 2 parts: one is a vue powered SPA, the other is a regular build. We're tying to find the best way to share styles across both, without having to load the SPA related styles when loading a regular page. Hope that makes sense.